# Using localStorage to save Google Maps and driving directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to utilize localStorage with Google Maps to save the start, end, and driving directions to local storage so user input is retained after closing the active browser window. I'm pretty sure I can add functions here:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  directionsService.route(
    {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: "DRIVING",
    },
    function (response, status) {
      if (status === "OK") {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

I have nested this function in the above function:

```
function showData() {
  localStorage.setItem("startData", JSON.stringify(start));
  localStorage.setItem("endData", JSON.stringify(end));

  var sData = localStorage.getItem("startData");
  var eData = localStorage.getItem("endData");

  var sObject = JSON.parse(sData);
  var eObject = JSON.parse(eData);
}
```

I am not seeing any JavaScript errors, and using the developer tools I can see the items being written into local storage.  However, when I reload or close the tab the user choices reset even though the local storage values are written.

How can I make the user choices persist when the application is refreshed?

Comment: What is `end` (`end.addEventListener("click", showData, false);`)?  Are you getting any javascript errors?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the line in question and have updated the original post.  I am not seeing errors, and the values are being written to local storage.  However, on refresh or closing the window and going back the chosen values reset.  Local storage still has the retained values.

Comment: I don't see localStorage.getItem anywhere. Do you use it?

Comment: It is in the 2nd function (showData) I separated out to show what I added to the base Google JS.

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: `start` and `end` look like that are strings.  Why are you calling `JSON.stringify` on them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I figured it out.  I was able to get what I needed with this loop:

```
if (
    first &&
    localStorage.getItem("startData") &&
    localStorage.getItem("endData")
  ) {
    start = localStorage.getItem("startData");
    end = localStorage.getItem("endData");
  } else {
    start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  }
```